# Angular Run *ngFor on particular Indexes Defined in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am using a *ngFor loop but I only want the loop to run on particular indexes defined in an array (i.e. indexArray = [454,640]).

If I try this, and the indexArray has two or more elements, it does not work. But If the array has only one element (i.e. indexArray=[565]) it works.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <table *ngIf="i == indexArray">
```

Comment: So you only want to display the items at index 454 and 640 from the `items` array? Is that your goal?

Comment: Use <table *ngIf="indexArray.indexOf(i) >= 0">; In your case, you tried to compare with `==` this operator will convert the operand on the right hand to number(`Number([565]) => 565` that why it equal to 565)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.indexOf(i)` and check whether it is in your `indexArray` variable.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <table *ngIf="indexArray.indexOf(i)> -1"> 
  <!-- REST OF THE CODE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <table *ngIf="indexArray.includes(i)">
    enter code here...
  </table>
</div>
```

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-tu-5mu69?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

create index array like this

```
public indexArray: array = [454,640];
```

do like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <table *ngIf="indexArray.indexOf(i)> -1">
    enter code here...
  </table>
</div>
```

let me know if you have any doubt.